# How to get selected product's price and show it on table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

so the requirement is to have a table which allows the user to create a new estimate online. I went as far as adding rows/ deleting them, having my DB's product list on the product field. But once I select the product, I would like the field 'Price' to pull up its price.

Here's the code I am currently using:

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

<TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txt"/></TD>
        <TD>
            <SELECT name="country" onchange="getPrice(this.value, this.closest('tr').rowIndex);">
                <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 

                echo '<option value="' .$row['nom'] . '">'.$row['nom'].'</option>'; }

                ?>


            </SELECT>
        </TD>

        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txt"/></TD>


    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Since PHP is server side, you would need to either: Collect the prices in some kind of hidden javascript (json maybe) array. OR Use something like AJAX to retrieve the information later on. If you want a preview over the first option (since that one is fairly easy) let me know.

Comment: A preview of the first option would be great, or any links which might help. Thank you

Comment: Hi, I found the problem, do you want to add me to skype? user: Xyvander  (Sorry for the long wait, I had to go to france for work x3)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what I assume is that your javascript function `getPrice(name, tablecell)` should retrieve the price stored in your database and puts it's price-value into the given table cell.

Before I write out a possible solution, I would like to add: This solution will keep the values from the database in a client-side array. Thus visible for any user, reviewing the code of your page. This shouldn't be an issue if you only store non-critical information though.

```js
// For testing purpose i filled in a mini-json, but in  
// the PHP-example later this post you will find a short
// example how to fill this with PHP from your database
var prices = { 
  'test_prod_1' : 16.46, 
  'test_prod_2' : 21.55,
  'test_prod_3' :  7.4
};


function getPrice( prodID, tableCell )
{
  if (typeof prices[prodID] !== 'undefined')
    tableCell.innerHTML  = '&euro;' + prices[prodID];  // Get the price from the pre-loaded price information
  else
    tableCell.innerHTML  = '?';
    
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click me" onClick="javascript:getPrice('test_prod_2', document.getElementById('test_cell'));">

<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5>
  <tr>
    <td>Product name</td>
    <td>price</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td id="test_cell"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And then with `PHP` You would be able to create this price list dynamically. But, remember that the data is visible client side, so this example will only select the price and name/id data. Make sure to edit the variable names to the ones you use.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var prices = <?php

    $js_pricelist = array();

    // Retireve the information from the server's database. Assume that $result is a result set in an ASSOC
    foreach( $result as $row )
        $js_pricelist[ $row['prodID'] ] = $row['prodPrice'];

    echo JSON_Encode( $js_pricelist );

    ?>
</script>
```

*Please check the last script as I haven't tested it yet, and is meant more to give you an idea of the possibilities*

**Conclusion:** The main idea is, that once you load the page, you assemble a javascript object containing all price data (Using PHP). You `echo` this object to a javascript block, and make a function that reads from this newly created array/object to retrieve the price that corresponds to the product_id.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89925/discussion-on-answer-by-xyv-how-to-get-selected-products-price-and-show-it-on-t).